# Changing style of input without display:none

Tags: javascript, html, css

A common way to replace a standard input is `display:none` the input, and then add a `background-image` to the label.

**CSS:**

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}
input[type="checkbox"]+label {
  background: url('../images/checkbox_unchecked.png') left center no-repeat;
  background-size: 25px;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
  background: url('../images/checkbox_checked.png') left center no-repeat;
  background-size: 25px;
}
```

The problem: The HTML is broken afterwards. When i want to change the direction of the elements, I have to change it inside the CSS (`background: right`).

How can I change the image/style of an input field without make it `display:none` first, and then change the background image? It has to work in Android 2.3.

EDIT: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ab0xwfcs/).

Comment: do you have a fiddle of what you are tying to do

Comment: I have added a JSFiddle.

Comment: You specified that it needs to work in older browsers - how old?

Comment: do you need to have both directions?

Comment: @Don Android 2.3 stock. And yes. i want to add a simple rtl to change the direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple fix for your `rtl` issue (assuming that is the main problem here, based on your JSFiddle demo), is to also style on the `dir` attribute when set to "rtl":

```css
.styles[dir="rtl"] input[type="radio"]+label {
    background-position: right;        /* Set the background position to the right. */
    padding-left: 0;                   /* Reset the left padding on the label. */
    padding-right: 35px;               /* Give the label some right padding. */
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ab0xwfcs/3/).

---

Everything I've used above should work on Android 2.3 according to [**Can I Use...**](http://caniuse.com/#search=adjacent%20sibling).

Answer (score 0):

You can some css that acts on the `rtl` attribute:

```
.styles[dir="rtl"] input[type="radio"]+label {
   padding: 0 35px 0 0;
   background-position: right center;
}
```

Here's your demo on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ab0xwfcs/2/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the support of this method, but you could also use the CSS `:before` instead of setting background positions for each direction.

```
.styles input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
.styles input[type="radio"]+label:before {
    content:"";
    display:inline-block;
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    background:red;
}
.styles input[type="radio"]:checked+label:before {
    content:"";
    display:inline-block;
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    background:pink;
}
```

[Demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ab0xwfcs/4/)

---

You can also use this method on the input itself, without setting it's `display` to `none`.
(This will create an extra element, that will hide the default one under.)

```
input[type="radio"]:after {
    content:"";
    display:inline-block;
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    background:gray;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked:after {
    content:"";
    display:inline-block;
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    background:pink;
    position:relative;
}
```